# Uso de comillas simples y dobles dentro de un echo

Tags: php, javascript

Quisiera saber cómo puedo hacer esto correctamente:

```
echo "<div class='table-row nocomp' id='t1' onclick='getTask1('t1','https://asd.com',5);'>"
```

El problema, como pueden ver, está aquí: `'t1','https://asd.com',5` donde estoy usando comillas simples dentro de otras comillas simples, pero no puedo hacerlo con las otras porque el echo las está usando.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Alguien me lo puede corregir?

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente escápalas

```
echo "<div class='table-row nocomp' id='t1' onclick=\"getTask1('t1','https://asd.com',5);\">"
```

Cualquier caracter se puede escapar anteponiendo una diagonal invertida, incluso para escapar la diagonal invertida es necesaria una diagonal invertida

Answer (score 0):

Prueba colocando el echo en comillas simple, y remplazando las otras por dobles

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```html
echo '<div class="table-row nocomp" id="t1" onclick="getTask1("t1","https://asd.com",5);>'
```